# Error: my variable is null

Tags: javascript

I have an error in my simple javascript code.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" value="Hello" />
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
 var txt2 = (null == document.getElementById('txt2').value)? "" : document.getElementById('txt2').value;
 alert(txt2);
</script>
```

I know that the element called txt2 does not exist, but I want that if an element does not exist variable txt2 will be assigned a default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2') ? document.getElementById('txt2').value : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You where comparing null against the value of txt2, which doesn't exist. This might work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value; 
  var txt2 = (null == document.getElementById('txt2')) ? "" : document.getElementById('txt2').value;
  alert(txt2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check the [***truthiness***](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html) of the value returned by `document.getElementById()`.

```
var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value,
    txt2_element = document.getElementById('txt2'),
    txt2 = txt2_element ? '' : txt2_element.value;

alert(txt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
var txt2Element = document.getElementById('txt2');
var txt2 = (txt2Element != null) ? txt2Element.value : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the value is `null`, just check if the element is null:

```
var txt2 = ( document.getElementById('txt2') === null )? "" : document.getElementById('txt2').value;
```